# ajax- put the .php called (by url) inside the main page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to put the .php page called (by url) inside the main page in order to keep all my dynamic variables. In my example $variable1path is not found because it is defined dynamically on my main page that has the ajax function.

my script for better understanding

```
<script>   
    $(document).on("click", "#div", function(e){   
            e.preventDefault();
            var textdata = $('#demo').val();
            mydata= 'testdata='+textdata;
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:mydata,  
                url:'external.php',
                success:function(data) {                
                    if(data){
                      alert('OK');
                      $("#demo").html(data);
                    }else{
                      alert('Not OK');
                    }
                  }
            });
        });
</script>
```

and my external.php

```
<?php
$data_to_write = $_POST['testdata'];
$file_path = '$variable1path.txt'; //$variable1path is defined on my main page
$file_handle = fopen($file_path, 'w'); 
fwrite($file_handle, $data_to_write);
fclose($file_handle);
$myfile = fopen('$variable1path.txt', 'r'); //$variable1path is defined on my main page
 while(!feof($myfile)) {
          echo fgets($myfile);
    }
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: If `$variablepath` is defined in the calling page, send it in the data you include in the AJAX request

Comment: ok I'll dig that way. thanks for the tip =)

Comment: Hey Rory, No success with your method and my code... If you have an other idea please share ;). thx

Comment: Sure, I added it as an answer for you to make what you need to do clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$variable1path` is defined in the calling page, send it in the data you include in the AJAX request:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#div", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      testdata: $('#demo').val(),
      variable1path: '<? echo $variable1path ?>'
    },
    url: 'external.php',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data) {
        console.log('OK');
        $("#demo").html(data);
      } else {
        console.log('Not OK');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Then in your PHP you can retrieve the values through `$_POST`:

```
<?php
  $data_to_write = $_POST['testdata'];
  $variable1path = $_POST['variable1path'];

  // your php logic here...
?>
```

Comment: Isn't `variable1path: <? echo "'$variable1path'" ?>` better?

Comment: To me the single set of quotes in JS look neater, but either would work fine.

Comment: I took my time because I'm learning in the same time, so I want to understand each lines. thanks a lot for your time ! that's very kind ! Have a lovely day !

Comment: you've impacted my day BIG time ! =)

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help :)